# SQL field values not accurately updated

Tags: sql, field

If records are updated, it'll be marked with Y and the latest version will be marked with null. The CreationDate of the latest updated record should be taken from the ModificationDate of the previous record. But the field isn't correctly updated as seen in the screenshot. Does anyone know how to solve this error?

**If the CreationDate field value is accurate, the records should be in the order of no. 6, 8, 7**
[image]

```
CREATE TRIGGER CloneAfterUpdate ON ProcessList
AFTER UPDATE
AS
IF (UPDATE (Amount) OR UPDATE (NAME))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ProcessListHist (
        ID
        ,NAME
        ,Amount
        ,CreationDate
        ,Edited
        ,ModificationDate
        )
    SELECT ID
        ,NAME
        ,Amount
        ,CreationDate
        ,'Y'
        ,GETDATE()
    FROM deleted

    UPDATE ProcessList
    SET ProcessList.CreationDate = ProcessListHist.ModificationDate
    FROM ProcessList
    INNER JOIN ProcessListHist ON ProcessList.ID = ProcessListHist.ID
END

UPDATE ProcessList
SET Amount = 9800
WHERE NAME = 'Rachel'

SELECT *
FROM ProcessList

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM ProcessListHist
ORDER BY ID ASC ,CreationDate ASC
```

**--- Updated ---**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ProcessList
(
    Edited              varchar(1),
    ID                  integer         NOT NULL,
    Name                varchar(30)     NOT NULL,
    Amount              smallmoney      NOT NULL,
    CreationDate        datetime        DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    ModificationDate    datetime,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID, CreationDate)
)


CREATE TABLE dbo.ProcessListHist
(
    Edited              varchar(1),
    ID                  integer         NOT NULL,
    Name                varchar(30)     NOT NULL,
    Amount              smallmoney      NOT NULL,
    CreationDate        datetime        NOT NULL,
    ModificationDate    datetime,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID, CreationDate)
)
```

Comment: I think it would really help if you specify the table structures you are using, because right now we are forced to guess them. The primary key of both tables are ID + CreationDate?

Comment: @eyeballs Your Edited column is probably redundant. You can use only `CreationDate` and `ModificationDate` for it. So not updated records would have `ModificationDate` NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UPDATE` in your trigger is not filtering anything, so it will go through all rows returned by

```
FROM ProcessList
INNER JOIN ProcessListHist ON ProcessList.ID = ProcessListHist.ID
```

and assign every `ModificationDate` to the `ProcessList` table, each time overwriting the previous value, and therefore you end up with the last one, whatever that is. You need to get the data of the modified row only, so you need to join the `delete` table, like this:

```
UPDATE PL
SET PL.CreationDate = PLH.ModificationDate
FROM ProcessList PL
INNER JOIN deleted on PL.ID = deleted.ID AND PL.CreationDate = deleted.CreationDate
INNER JOIN ProcessListHist PLH ON PL.ID = PLH.ID AND PLH.CreationDate = deleted.CreationDate
```

By joining with `delete`, you first get the modified row, and then you can join the history table to get the new modification date.

But if you paid attention, you are joining this last table just to get the `datetime` you already had (when you called `GETDATE`), so you can simplify the trigger a bit like this:

```
DECLARE @Now DATETIME
SELECT @Now = GETDATE()
INSERT INTO ProcessListHist (
    ID
    ,NAME
    ,Amount
    ,CreationDate
    ,Edited
    ,ModificationDate
    )
SELECT ID
    ,NAME
    ,Amount
    ,CreationDate
    ,'Y'
    ,@Now
FROM deleted

UPDATE PL
SET PL.CreationDate = @Now
FROM ProcessList PL
INNER JOIN deleted on PL.ID = deleted.ID AND PL.CreationDate = deleted.CreationDate
```

Does `ProcessList` need the `ModificationDate` field? Why do you need the `Edited` field? From what I see, it's always `NULL` in one and always `Y` in the other. If you remove them all, you can do the last query like this:

```
SELECT NULL AS Edited, ID, Name, Amount, CreationDate, NULL AS ModificationDate
FROM ProcessList

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Y', ID, Name, Amount, CreationDate, ModificationDate
FROM ProcessListHist
ORDER BY ID ASC ,CreationDate ASC
```

Comment: Ah yes i do need the ModificationDate field as my database allows users to import excel files into it, so if they edit something outside of the database, it shows. My database works how I want it to now. Thank you so much for your time and help! :> @Andrew

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reasons for making your life so complicated with the way you are currently using.

Lets understand this one by one. You have following table structure and you have two operations i.e. `Insert` and `Delete`.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ProcessList
(
    Edited              varchar(1),
    ID                  integer         NOT NULL,
    Name                varchar(30)     NOT NULL,
    Amount              smallmoney      NOT NULL,
    CreationDate        datetime        DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    ModificationDate    datetime,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID, CreationDate)
)
```

> **Insert**

In case of INSERT, Edit is going to be null (which in itself a design flaw, will discuss later), ID-Name-Amount-CreationDate will have a value and ModificationDate will be NULL again. This is simple use case.

```
Insert into YouTableName values (null,4035,'Rachel Zane',1000,getdate(),null)
```

> **Update/Edit**

In case of EDIT, you need to updated EDIT column to 'Y' and you will update rest of the fields, and simply copy `ModificationDate` to `CreationDate` like below

```
Update table
set Edit = 'Y',
Name = <NewNameIfAny>,
Amount = <NewAmountIfAny>,
CreationDate = ModificationDate,
ModificationDate = Getdate()
```

That's it and you are done, and in this way you don't need any `Trigger`. And I don't see any use case for the same. You can read [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/123074/sql-triggers-and-when-or-when-not-to-use-them) the use case to use trigger.

**DesignFlaw**: When you know that you are either going to be 'Y' or 'null' in EDIT column, then why didn't you make it of `bit` type which is faster than anything. Bit will act as a flag for you. Initially you can mark it as `False (0)`, and whenever any edit occurs, then update this to `True (1)`. That's it. And you can rename your column to `IsEdited`.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the flaw part! Will implement it in my database :> thank you so much!